# Animated Gif in Joomla

Tags: module-display, editor, media-manager

I have an animated gif that I was looking at putting into a Joomla Module.  It is an icon that as you hover over it the icon changes.  Built in Fireworks, when I pull it up on an html page it works just fine, however I am having all kinds of problems bringing it into Joomla.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how they do this? Am I tackling this the wrong way?  The items have to be customized so I'm not trying to use some extension or other, I just want to be able to put this in a Custom HTML module. I have the Adobe Creative Cloud for editing, and JCE for Joomla. (with all plugins).  I don't want to use iFrame as this is an entirely responsive site using Themler.

Comment: What do you mean by "all kinds of problems bringing it into Joomla"? Also, show us your efforts.

Comment: https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/documentation/24-image-manager/83-rollover

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no reason why animated Gifs should fail to display in Joomla, hover effect or not, so either you have an error in your code, or something else is causing `"all kinds of problems"`. If you describe your problem with more detail it possible that someone can help you with the issue.

Normally, the JCE editor uses this code to add hover effect to an image:

```
<img onmouseover="this.src='http://heathersanimations.com/autobadges/auto39.gif';"
 onmouseout="this.src='http://placehold.it/96x96';"
 src="http://placehold.it/96x96" alt="Rollover" >
```

This code works fine in Joomla, I just tested it.

Comment: It's an animated gif, not a rollover, so for instance the background fades out as the user hovers over, once they are no longer rolling over, it no longer fades.  I'm guessing it sounds like I'm setting something up incorrectly with the animated gif would you agree?  Or do you think there is something else that I can do?